# flutter multiprovider and consumer rebuild screen many times

Tags: flutter, flutter-provider

I am building an application using Flutter and I use provider package for state management  but I noticed the widgets are rebuild many times
I set here the ProductsScreen.dart file as example but I face this issue in all pages and widgets in the application
here is my code

main.dart

```
return MultiProvider(
  providers: [
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => ProductsController()),
    ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (ctx) => OrdersController()),
  ],
  child:
  LocaleBuilder(
    builder: (locale)=> MaterialApp(
      localizationsDelegates: Locales.delegates,
      supportedLocales: Locales.supportedLocales,
      locale: locale,
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: AppTheme.lightTheme,
      onGenerateRoute: AppRoutes.generateRoute,
      initialRoute: '/',
    ),
  ),
);
```

and this is mainScreen.dart file  and I see ProductsScreen() rebuild many times

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return
  Directionality(
    textDirection: TextDirection.rtl,
    child: Scaffold(
    body: SafeArea(
      child:
        ProductsScreen(),
     
    ),
),
  );
}
```

here is ProductsScreen.dart file witch is rebuild many times

```
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
ProductsController productsController= Provider.of<ProductsController>(context);
productsController.getProducts(ServerProducts());
return
 Consumer<ProductsController>(builder:(x,productsController,_){

 return productsController.productsList.isEmpty
     ? Center(
   child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
 )
     : ListView.builder(
     itemCount: productsController.productsList.length,
     itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => ProductCard(
         product: productsController.productsList[index],
         increaseByOne: () {
           productsController.increaseByOne(index);
         },
         decreaseByOne: () {
           productsController.decreaseByOne(index);
         }));
   });


 }
```

Comment: Whenever you call `notifyListeners` from any provider's code, all the widgets which are wrapped into a `Consumer` or using `context.watch` etc. of the corresponding provider type will be rebuilt.

Comment: i call the method only once  but it rebuild the screen many times

Comment: It might be because you call `Provider.of<ProductsController>(context)` from the `build` method. Try `context.read<ProductsController>()` instead.

Comment: works but it doesn't listen for changes because it doesn't know about notifylistiners()

Comment: The `Consumer` should be called each time `notifyListeners()` is invoked. To invoke it you need to call `getProducts` from somewhere but not inside the build method because that triggers the multiple rebuilds.